# TCP IP Android Client (phone) and PC server in c#

Tags: c#, android

I want to send large file from my phone to PC server which is written in c#, The code is below,

Client side;

```
    File sdFile=new File(mRcordFilePath);

    byte[] mybytearray = new byte[(int) sdFile.length()];
    FileInputStream fis = null;
    try {
        fis = new FileInputStream(sdFile);
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    BufferedInputStream bis = new BufferedInputStream(fis);
    DataInputStream dis = new DataInputStream(bis);
    OutputStream os;

    try {

        os = socket.getOutputStream();
        DataOutputStream dos = new DataOutputStream(os);
        String name=sdFile.getName();
        dos.writeUTF(name);
        dos.writeLong(mybytearray.length);
        int read;
        while((read = dis.read(mybytearray)) != -1) {
            dos.write(mybytearray, 0, read);
        }

        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                "Veri Gönderildi !", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    } catch (UnknownHostException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Server side;

part of server;

```
            int fileNameLen = 1;
            String content = String.Empty;
            StateObject state = (StateObject)ar.AsyncState;
            Socket handler = state.workSocket;
            int bytesRead = handler.EndReceive(ar);
            if (bytesRead > 0)
            {

                if (flag == 0)
                {
                    fileNameLen = BitConverter.ToInt32(state.buffer, 0);
                    string fileName = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(state.buffer, 4, fileNameLen);
                    receivedPath = @"C:\Users\Hankishan\Desktop\kayıtlar\" + fileName;
                flag++;
            }
            if (flag >= 1)
            {
                BinaryWriter writer = new BinaryWriter(File.Open(receivedPath, FileMode.Append));
                if (flag == 1)
                {
                    writer.Write(state.buffer, 4 + fileNameLen, bytesRead - (4 + fileNameLen));
                    flag++;
                }
                else
                writer.Write(state.buffer, 0, bytesRead);
                writer.Close();
                handler.BeginReceive(state.buffer, 0, StateObject.BufferSize, 0,
                new AsyncCallback(ReadCallback), state);
            }

        }
        else
        {
            Invoke(new MyDelegate(LabelWriter));
        }
```

İf  I run this code,
while receiving the file (for instance 123.wav) there is an error in this row;

```
string fileName = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(state.buffer, 4, fileNameLen);
```

if  I change the code as;

```
fileNameLen = state.buffer[1];
string fileName = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(state.buffer, 2, fileNameLen);
```

is ok. But in this time received file is corrupted, is not played in PC,
what can I do? What is the problem?

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem. The code is here;

public void ReadCallback (IAsyncResult ar)

{

```
            int fileNameLen = 1;
            String content = String.Empty;
            StateObject state = (StateObject)ar.AsyncState;



            Socket handler = state.workSocket;
            int bytesRead = handler.EndReceive(ar);

            if (bytesRead > 0)
            {
                if (flag == 0)
                {
                    fileNameLen = state.buffer[1];
                    //fileNameLen = BitConverter.ToInt32(state.buffer, 0);
                    string fileName = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(state.buffer, 2, fileNameLen);
                    receivedPath = @"C:\Users\Hankishan\Desktop\kayitlar\" + fileName;
                flag++;
            }
            if (flag >= 1)
            {
                BinaryWriter writer = new BinaryWriter(File.Open(receivedPath, FileMode.Append));
                if (flag == 1)
                {

                    writer.Write(state.buffer, 2 + fileNameLen, bytesRead - (2 + fileNameLen));
                    flag++;
                }
                else
                {
                    if (flag == 2)
                    {
                        for (int i = 0; i < state.buffer.Length; i++)
                        {
                            if (i + 8 == 1023)
                                break;
                            state.buffer[i] = state.buffer[i + 8];
                        }
                        writer.Write(state.buffer, 0, bytesRead);
                        flag++;
                    }else
                        writer.Write(state.buffer, 0, bytesRead);
                }
                writer.Close();
                handler.BeginReceive(state.buffer, 0, StateObject.BufferSize, 0,
                new AsyncCallback(ReadCallback), state);
            }

        }
        else
        {
            Invoke(new MyDelegate(LabelWriter));
        }

        }
```